# element-ui dialog be obscured for mask layer

Tags: vue.js

I used Vue element-ui.

code:

```
<el-table-column fixed="right"><template scope="scope"></template></el-table-column>
```

In "template" label,I write a dialog,but it is obscured for mask layer.

Removed the "fixed" property will be normal.

But I need this property.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2pqs.png)

Comment: try with v-if in element

Answer (score 0):

Maybe You can set z-index property on your template.